# Is there a way to condense the spacing between points on a bubble plot?

Tags: ggplot2, format, geom

Hopefully this is a quick answer.  I just created a bubble plot in ggplot2 to showcase abundances of taxa in certain environments, snapshot shown below:

[image]

Is there a way I may "condense" all this white space?

Thanks in advance,

J

Comment: Edit: action of ggsave() with parameters: width = 4, height = 4, dpi = 200 compressed the image, but if there's a way to do that more "sustainably" within the actual ggplot code, I would appreciate any pointers!

Comment: The quick answer is... no.  Graphics depend on the graphics device aspect ratio and resolution, so modification of the width, height, and dpi for `ggsave()` is precisely how you squish and stretch your plots.  Text does not scale with data points, so to really do fine-tuning you may have to play with text sizes too.  It is a dance we all do to create our lovely `ggplot` graphs.  :)

Answer (score 0):

With the help of chemdork123 and an hour of messing around, I would like to post the solution to my question!

Two ways to make bubble plots more aesthetically pleasing by minimizing white space:

1. `ggsave()` parameters width, height, and dpi.
2. `scale_size_continuous(range = c(1,15))`with manual adjustment of circle sizes.